# Testing with rosmake -a -t fails because a test did not run. What's wrong?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running 'rosmake -a -t' I get some test failures attributed to 'test did not run. Expected results in xxx.xml'. How can I determine what's wrong and fix it?

An abbreviated example:

> ERRORS/FAILURES:
> [test_tf2.test_convert/test_ran][FAILURE]---------------------------------------   Unable to find test results for
> TEST-test_convert.xml, test did not
> run. Expected results in
> /home/teh/.ros/test_results/test_tf2/TEST-test_convert.xml
>   PACKAGES:
>
> - test_tf2
>
>   SUMMARY
>
>   - RESULT: FAIL
>   - TESTS: 5
>   - ERRORS: 0
>   - FAILURES: 5

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32196/testing-with-rosmake--a--t-fails-because-a-test-did-not-run.-what%27s-wrong?/) by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest going into the directory and trying to execute the tests manually to get more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0